# How to do dynamic orderby in LINQ?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, lambda

I am trying to get sort the data based on the user input. But the orderby clause is not executed in LINQ. How do i do that ??
Here is my code...

```
 [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult SortData(String colName , String sortorder)
    {
        using( EmployeeDB db = new EmployeeDB( ) )
        {
            if( sortorder == "desc" )
            {
                var JsonData = new
                {
                    Data = (from emp in db.Employees
                            orderby colName descending
                            select new
                            {
                                EId = emp.EId ,
                                EmployeeName = emp.EmployeeName
                            }).ToList( )
                };
                return Json( JsonData , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet );
            }
            else
            {
                var JsonData = new
                {
                    Data = (from emp in db.Employees
                            orderby colName
                            select new
                            {
                                EId = emp.EId ,
                                EmployeeName = emp.EmployeeName
                            }).ToList( )
                };
                return Json( JsonData , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet );
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to do something like this to make it work:

```
var colName= "EmployeeName";

var Column= typeof(Employee).GetProperty(colName);


Data = (from emp in db.Employees
        select new
        {
         EId = emp.EId ,
         EmployeeName = emp.EmployeeName
        })
        .AsEnumerable()
        .OrderBy(emp => Column.GetValue(emp, null))
        .ToList();
```

or:

```
 Data = (from emp in db.Employees
            select new
            {
             EId = emp.EId ,
             EmployeeName = emp.EmployeeName
            })
            .AsEnumerable()
            .OrderBy(i => i.GetType().GetProperty(colName).GetValue(i, null))
            .ToList();
```

Comment: @Eshan, are you sure order by object will work? I suggested the same, but I'm interested.

Comment: i have not tested it, but it should work.

Comment: I tried with both of code... It dint work...  :(

Comment: I am getting this error.. 

LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Object GetValue(System.Object, System.Object[])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

Comment: updated in question what you did?

Comment: in both cases you get same exception?

Comment: I tried with both of your answer... but i am getting the same error :(

Comment: i updated answer try that way

Answer (score 0):

```
from emp in db.Employees
orderby colName
...
```

Wrong. `colName` is the same for every employee. It have to be something like `emp.EmployeeName`.

In your case, I think, you better to try Reflection to get actual values of specific column of specific employee. Smth like that:

```
order by emp.GetType().GetProperty("colName").GetValue(emp, null)
```

Ugly. Not sure it will work while value is not casted to it's actual type.

Comment: No.. Its not getting sorted..